# Awful deformation when rigging clothes to a character model with data transfer

Tags: modifiers, rigging

I'm trying rig a jacket and shirt to a character model I've created. In order to get them to share the character rig, I used the data transfer modifier. However, I'm getting some terrible deformation around the armpits as a result.

Can anyone suggest which settings within the modifier might solve the issue? Or is there perhaps something else I've overlooked?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's a screenshot of the issue.[image]

Comment: Don't use Data Transfer for this. It requires the source and destination vertices to be in exactly the same location. Presumably, your shirt mesh doesn't occupy exactly the same space as your body mesh, so avoid this approach. Instead, bind the shirt object to the same armature to which the body is currently attached, yet as a separate operation, and then use a shrinkwrap modifier on the shirt to ensure that it hugs the body properly during deformation.

Comment: if you can't get the above solution to work, consider, as an alternative, simply deleting unseen geometry -- where arms and sleeves would normally collide, for example -- so that no meshes poke through any other meshes, because they aren't actually present. You may find that these mesh parts have to be joined together and cleaned up to make them all one continuous mesh afterwards. But if your character was built this way, there are a lot of deformation issues you simply wouldn't have to worry about any more.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll probably try the first way. What do you mean by "bind" the shirt object to the same armature? How do I do that? Parent with automatic weights?

Comment: Yes. All I mean by "bind" is to parent the mesh to the armature. Various people have been getting confused lately by my choice to use the word "bind" in this context, so maybe I should stop. I think it comes from Maya, but I haven't used that program in a long time. So it's possible that Maya doesn't use the term that way anymore either.

Comment: To be fair, when I searched around after reading your response, I saw "bind" being used a lot. I couldn't get the first method to work for me. However, it seems using data transfer and smoothing the weights mitigates the problem to a significant degree.

The game I'm making is fairly low lit, so hopefully it's good enough and will export to Unity without issue.